# "no descriptor for this position" Oracle error

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

We're trying a basic insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO HOLIDAY (HOLIDAY_TYPE_CODE, CALENDAR_NAME, HOLIDAY_DATE, DESCRIPTION, CREATE_TS,
UPDATE_TS)  VALUES (2, 'CZK', '17-NOV-2009', NULL, SYSDATE, NULL);
```

And we get this error:

```
ORA-24334: no descriptor for this position
```

What are we doing wrong here??

Comment: I see you answered your own question here, but I had to add....
DO NOT DEPEND UPON IMPLICIT DATE CONVERSIONS! It is very bad practice to insert a string value (17-NOV-2009) into a date field. The implicit conversion depends upon NLS settings and so on, so it isn't very portable. It is much better to perform an explicit conversion using to_char(). If this was a one-off query in Toad, well, it doesn't matter. But I'd not want someone to think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this in TOAD.

It worked in sqlplus.

Restarted TOAD and I was good.

Answer (score 0):

It is working after restarting the TOAD.Some issue with TOAD while executing this.